# backgroung fill pattern image not export

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas, svg

I am working with the D3 library.

I want to export svg as a png image , check below code what is shown in this jsfiddle, when we are exporting svg as a png, pattern background image not exporting in png image. kindely check and revert.

I read that something like this can be accomplished using svg's patterns. So here is some of the D3 code I am using to append an image into a pattern:

```js
d3.select("#downloadsvg").on("click", function(){
     var html = d3.select("#svg > .pattern > svg")
           .attr("version", 1.1)
           .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
           .node().parentNode.innerHTML;

     //console.log(html);
     var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(html);
     var img = '<img src="'+imgsrc+'">'; 
     d3.select("#svgdataurl").html(img);


     var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d");

     var image = new Image;
     image.src = imgsrc;
     image.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

      var canvasdata = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

      var pngimg = '<img src="'+canvasdata+'">'; 
        d3.select("#pngdataurl").html(pngimg);

      var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.download = "sample.png";
      a.href = canvasdata;
      a.click();
     };

   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="svg">
           <div class="pattern" style="margin: 25px;"><svg id="selectedsvg" width="250" height="250" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs> 
    <filter id="contrast">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1.5"></feGaussianBlur>
    <feComponentTransfer>
    <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="0 .5 1 1"></feFuncR>
    <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="0 .5 1"></feFuncG>
    <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="0"></feFuncB>
    </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>

    <filter id="brightness">
    <feComponentTransfer>
    <feFuncR type="linear" slope="5"></feFuncR>
    <feFuncG type="linear" slope="5"></feFuncG>
    <feFuncB type="linear" slope="5"></feFuncB>
    </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter> 

    <filter id="grayscale">
    <feColorMatrix values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
    0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
    0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
    0      0      0      1 0"></feColorMatrix> 
    </filter>

    <filter id="saturate">
    <feComponentTransfer>
    <feFuncR tableValues="1 .33 .33" type="table"></feFuncR>
    <feFuncG tableValues=".33 1 .33" type="table"></feFuncG>
    <feFuncB tableValues=".33 .33 1" type="table"></feFuncB>
    </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>


    <filter id="hue-rotate">
    <feComponentTransfer>
    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="1 0"></feFuncR>
    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="1 0"></feFuncG>
    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="1 0"></feFuncB>
    </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>


    <filter id="sepia">
    <feComponentTransfer>
    <feFuncR tableValues="0.15 .25" type="table"></feFuncR>
    <feFuncG tableValues=".01 .25" type="table"></feFuncG>
    <feFuncB tableValues="0 .09" type="table"></feFuncB>
    </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>

    <filter id="invert">
    <feComponentTransfer>
    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="1 0"></feFuncR>
    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="1 0"></feFuncG>
    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="1 0"></feFuncB>
    </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>

    <filter id="blur">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" result="outBlur"></feGaussianBlur>
    </filter>
    <pattern id="pattern1" height="100%" width="100%" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"> <image height="1px" width="1px" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://halyca.kiwis-and-brownies.de/demo3/img/Embroidery1.png"></image></pattern>
    <pattern id="pattern2" height="100%" width="100%" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"> <image height="1px" width="1px" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://halyca.kiwis-and-brownies.de/demo3/img/Embroidery2.png"></image></pattern>
    <pattern id="pattern3" height="100%" width="100%" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"> <image height="1px" width="1px" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://halyca.kiwis-and-brownies.de/demo3/img/Embroidery3.png"></image></pattern>
    <pattern id="pattern4" height="100%" width="100%" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"> <image height="1px" width="1px" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://halyca.kiwis-and-brownies.de/demo3/img/Embroidery4.png"></image></pattern>
</defs>
  <rect x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#FC7A04" id="1" filter="url(#blur)"></rect>
     <circle xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" id="c1" fill="url(#pattern-77)"></circle>
     <circle xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="40%" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" fill="#eee333" id="c2" filter="url(#blur)"></circle>
     <circle xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30%" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" id="c3" fill="url(#pattern-94)"></circle>
     <circle xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="20%" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" id="c4"></circle>
 
<defs><pattern id="pattern-94" height="30%" width="30%" x="-0.05" y="-0.030000000000000006" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"><image width="0.30000000000000004px" height="0.30000000000000004px" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://halyca.kiwis-and-brownies.de/media/configurator/embroidery/Embroidery4.png"></image></pattern></defs><defs><pattern id="pattern-77" height="20%" width="20%" x="-0.02" y="0.01" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"><image width="0.20000000000000004px" height="0.20000000000000004px" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://halyca.kiwis-and-brownies.de/media/configurator/embroidery/Embroidery1.png"></image></pattern></defs><text x="8" y="238" id="text-21" font-size="27" font-family="Times New Roman" style="fill: rgb(184, 19, 59);" font-weight="bold" font-style="italic">sadja</text><path d="M9.5,15L118.5,97" stroke="black" stroke-width="1px"></path><path d="M119.5,98L216.5,9" stroke="black" stroke-width="1px"></path><path d="M217.5,10L217.5,10" stroke="black" stroke-width="1px"></path><path d="M217.5,10L9.5,15" stroke="black" stroke-width="1px"></path><path d="M10.5,16L10.5,16" stroke="black" stroke-width="1px"></path><path d="M11.5,35L11.5,35" stroke="black" stroke-width="1px"></path><path d="M11.5,35L11.5,35" stroke="black" stroke-width="1px"></path><path d="M206.5,143L206.5,143" stroke="black" stroke-width="1px"></path><path d="M206.5,143L206.5,143" stroke="black" stroke-width="1px"></path><path d="M163.5,32L163.5,32" stroke="black" stroke-width="1px"></path></svg> </div>
          </div>
                    <canvas id="canvas1" width='380' height='378' hidden></canvas>
                    <button id="downloadsvg"> Save Svg</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to embed your image into base64 using dataurl. after you can able to download the png with background